# Writing Haskell FFI for read system call

Tags: linux, haskell, system-calls, ffi

The `read` function is defined like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>

ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t len)
```

I want to write a Haskell FFI for this. This is my attempt (which doesn't compile):

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "read" c_read :: CInt -> Ptr () -> CSize -> IO CSsize

read :: Int -- ^ file descriptor
     -> Int64 -- ^ Bytes to allocate
     -> Word64 -- ^ Read upto this many bytes
     -> IO (String, Int64)
read fd bytes len = do
  allocaBytes (fromIntegral bytes) (\ptr -> do
                       size <- c_read (fromIntegral fd) ptr (fromIntegral len)
                       dat <- peekByteOff (castPtr ptr) (fromIntegral size) :: IO String
                       return (dat, (fromIntegral size))
                    )
```

It doesn't compile because there is no instance of `String` for Storable. Any hints on how to write a FFI for this ?

Comment: I'd recommend returning a `ByteString` instead of a `String`, as the latter will imply a character encoding which may not be true. In order to create the `ByteString`, you'll likely want to `malloc` the buffer instead of using `allocaBytes`, and then reuse that pointer for the `ByteString`.

Comment: Your peek line is overly simplistic, actually incorrect since you are using `size` as the index from which to start reading.  Consider [`packCStringLen`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.1/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:packCStringLen)

Comment: Also, this API seems terribly dangerous.  At the least you should probably check `bytes >= len` so users can't say `read fd 0 5000`, right?  EDIT: Actually it's trickier than that.   `fromIntegral bytes :: some type >= fromIntegralLen :: that type` where the types match your casts / c binding.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Yeah, I know. I want to make it work and then worry about correctness. :)

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman Is this a reasonable start: https://gist.github.com/psibi/e01ae8e9fe760488685253916b27efbb ? I'm using `CString` as an intermediate type.

Comment: You shouldn't use `packCString` because the data you read might contain null characters.

Comment: @ReidBarton In that case, will replacing `packCString` with `packCStringLen ((castPtr ptr), fromIntegral size)` reasonable ?

Comment: Then it looks okay, though you could perhaps avoid the extra allocation and copy by working with bytestring internals. But unrelatedly, you should not make an unsafe foreign call to `read`, which can block!

Comment: @ReidBarton Thanks, that was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the suggestions of Michael Snoyman and Reid Barton, I finally came up with this solution as a start:

```
foreign import ccall safe "read" c_read :: CInt -> Ptr () -> CSize -> IO CSsize

read :: Int -- ^ file descriptor
     -> Int64 -- ^ Bytes to allocate
     -> Word64 -- ^ Read upto this many bytes
     -> IO (ByteString, Int64)
read fd bytes len = do
  (ptr :: Ptr ()) <- mallocBytes (fromIntegral bytes)
  size <- c_read (fromIntegral fd) ptr (fromIntegral len)
  bstring <- packCStringLen (castPtr ptr, fromIntegral size) 
  free ptr
  return (bstring, (fromIntegral size))
```

Answer (score 1):

[Foreign.C.String](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Foreign-C-String.html) is the traditional solution here.